# DevExpress: XtraGridView Custom column binding

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid, databound

Lets say that I have the two following classes

```
public class OtherClass
{
    public string OtherName{ get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string TheName { get; set; }
    public int TheAge { get; set; }
}
```

lets say that I bound the `XtraGrid` to the `Object` datasource (`MyClass`  )

Now, My scenario is that I want to populate the first column (`TheName`) when I click the `Editor button` with `OtherName` values came from list of `OtherClass` object (`List<OtherClass>`)

then finally transfer the whole Row back to `MyClass` object

is that possible?

Comment: You might want to word it a little better, What is the "Editor button" are you talking about having a LookupEdit with the source being a List<OtherClass> and when you select something from the LookupEdit you want that placed in "TheName" property of the current row? Happy to help but just need to understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe like this:

```
        List<MyClass> mylist = new List<MyClass>();
        mylist.Add(new MyClass() { TheName = "Kirk", TheAge = 56 });
        mylist.Add(new MyClass() { TheName = "Spock", TheAge = 403 });
        mygrid.DataSource = mylist;
        mygrid.MainView.PopulateColumns();

        List<OtherClass> all_names = new List<OtherClass>();
```

add existing names here :

```
        foreach (var item in mylist)
            all_names.Add( new OtherClass() { OtherName = item.TheName } );
```

continue with additional names:

```
        all_names.Add(new OtherClass() { OtherName = "Watson" });
        all_names.Add(new OtherClass() { OtherName = "Sherlock" });
```

create repositoryItemLookUpEdit1 via designer

```
        repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.DataSource = all_names;
        repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.DisplayMember = "OtherName";
        repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.ValueMember = "OtherName";
        ((DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView)mygrid.MainView).Columns[0].ColumnEdit = repositoryItemLookUpEdit1;
```

and your data should be fine